# Graph of Triangle wave

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I am trying to graph the following:

[image]

Using the following function:

[image]

And using this code:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
domain = -1 : 3,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
axis x line = center, 
axis y line = center,
every axis x label/.append style = {below},
every axis y label/.append style = {left},
samples = 100,
xtick = {-1, 1, 3},
xticklabels = {$-1$, $1$, $3$},
declare function = {
T(\x) = (2 / pi) * (1 / sin) * (sin * deg(pi * \x));
}, ]
\addplot[ultra thick, black] {T(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error: `\! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in '(2/pi)*(1/sin)*(sin*deg(pi*2Y1.0e0
]))').`

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: By the way, your sketch doesn't quite correspond to your function I think. For example with x=0, you have asin(sin(0)) which is 0, so the function passes through the origin. In your sketch, the function value is 1 at x=0.

Comment: Could be that the function itself is wrong!

Comment: It is probably simpler to draw `abs(Mod(\x,2)-1)`, which is the same function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sin` is a function, not a variable, and `sin^(-1)` is the inverse sine function, or arcsine, which is not the same as `1/sin(..)`. I think you want `T(\x) = (2 / pi) * rad(asin(sin(deg(pi * \x))));`. The `rad()` is needed because `asin` returns an angle in degrees, and you want it in radians I think.

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
  samples at={-1,-0.5,...,3}, % gives a data point every pi/4
  xlabel = $x$,
  ylabel = $y$,
  axis lines = center, 
  enlargelimits,
  every axis x label/.append style = {below},
  every axis y label/.append style = {left},
  xtick = {-1, 1, 3},
  %xticklabels = {$-1$, $1$, $3$}, % not needed, numbers are set in math mode by default
  declare function = {
    T(\x) = (2 / pi) * rad(asin(sin(deg(pi * \x))));
  }
]
\addplot[ultra thick, black] {T(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

## Edit

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel = $x$,
  ylabel = $y$,
  axis lines = center, 
  enlargelimits,
  every axis x label/.append style = {below},
  every axis y label/.append style = {left},
  xtick = {-1, 1, 3},
  xticklabel style={fill=white},
  clip=false,
  axis on top,
  name=ax
]
\addplot[ultra thick, black] coordinates {(-1,0)(0,1)(1,0)(2,1)(3,0)};

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1,1,3}{
  \addplot [dashed] coordinates {(#1,-0.3)(#1,1)};
}

\draw  [<->] (-1,-0.5) -- 
  node[below]{
     $\begin{aligned}
        2L &=2 \\ L&=1
     \end{aligned}$} (1, -0.5);

\end{axis}

\node [right=3mm,yshift=1cm] at (ax.outer east) {$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1+x, & x< 0 \\ 1-x, & x >0 \end{cases}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Torbjørn T. Another question, how do I do the part below? Where is 2L=2 and L=1?

Comment: @user151562 See update for one option.